# Why Windows 10 has some "useless hotkeys" which opens some links in browser?

Tags: windows-10, hotkeys

I'm currently on Windows 10 Pro 1909, and I noticed that pressing one of folowing hotkeys opens strange links in default browser:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> => `https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2044778`
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> => `https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2044769`
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> => `https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2044786`
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> => `https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2044782`
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> => `https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2044904`
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> => `https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2044481`
`...`

Why is that? Why I cant assign my hotkeys to them...?(normally speaking)

I know I can use AHK to redifine them **the HARD way**. I always thought that users *can choose*. I never seen such strange hotkeys in Windows 7.

**update**:

After looking through the web, I have noticed that it has something to do with the

```
HKCU\Software\Classes\ms-officeapp\Shell\Open\Command
```

Registry key, if you change it, then it will start opening it.

And by the comments: It is the Office 365 feature which is *integrated* in newer builds of Windows 10, and these hotkeys work even if you not have Office 365 installed.

The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> - is a new **OfficeKey**.

Related questions:

- [How to disable Office key keyboard shortcut opening Office app?](https://superuser.com/questions/1455857/how-to-disable-office-key-keyboard-shortcut-opening-office-app)
- [Launch a batch script as shell instead of explorer in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1533460/launch-a-batch-script-as-shell-instead-of-explorer-in-windows-10)

Comment: [Yes](https://superuser.com/questions/1533460/launch-a-batch-script-as-shell-instead-of-explorer-in-windows-10) it appears this is a feature of 1903 and 1909.  Due to this being a feature of File Explorer itself your options will be limited[.](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-10-starts-office-appoffice-apps-constantly/68cba06f-62b9-47d8-950f-17a90ffc5387?page=2)

Comment: So that means - this will be "default hotkeys"... sadly...